# Why does this XML code not create objects?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the simple XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <GV8APIDATA xmlns="gv8api-trayport-com">
        <ORDER Action="Query" />
    </GV8APIDATA>
```

Then I am using this code to parse the XML

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\data\data.xml");

var orders =
    (from order in xml.Root.Elements("GV8APIDATA").Elements("ORDER")
        select new Order
        {
            Action = order.Attribute("Action").Value
        }).ToList();
```

I have tried loads of different combinations of Desecendants, Elements, etc and nothing works?

I never get anything in orders

This should be really simple! What am I missing? It's probably something really obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't read the elements like that is because you need to support xml namespaces:

```
public static XNamespace ns = "gv8api-trayport-com";
var dataElements = document.Elements(ns + "GV8APIDATA");
```

You can also do a "quick'n'dirty hack" by checking the .LocalName of an element (which does equal "GV8APIDATA" instead of the fully qualified element name including the namespace).

I also think it's best to use XPath here if you want to grasp a specific value (But note that you might need to set up namespaces here as well).

```
var document = XDocument.Parse("your xml input");
var elements = document.XPathSelectElements("//GV8APIDATA/ORDER");
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    // read attribute here
}
```